how to use formatjs plugin in rspack's swc loader
Recently I migrated a application from webpack to rspack.
Previously we were using babel-loader to transpile. Now we decided to use rspack's builtin swc-loader.
We are using formatjs for intl support.
here is the swc-loader configuration for rspack
const js = {
  test: /\.js(x)?$/,
  exclude: [
    /node_modules/,
    path.join(config.root, config.paths.src, 'web', 'javascripts/vendors/'),
  ],
  loader: 'builtin:swc-loader',
  options: {
    jsc: {
      parser: {
        syntax: 'ecmascript',
        jsx: true,
      },
      transform: {
        react: {
          runtime: 'automatic',
          development: config.env === 'production',
          refresh: config.env === 'production',
        },
      },
      experimental: {
        plugins: [
          [
            '@formatjs/swc-plugin',
            {
              overrideIdFn: '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]',
              ast: true,
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
    type: 'javascript/auto',
    env: {
      targets: 'Chrome >= 48',
    },
  },
};

And here is the build error I am facing after using the formatjs plugin:

For reference, here is the explanation for the formatjs plugin
https://formatjs.io/docs/tooling/swc-plugin/
How can I use the formatjs plugin with rspack and swc loader?
